# here is an API that changes after some time I want previous data to be stored in an array and latest data too I dont how to figure this out?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want `data` state to be an array which adds up the data when the data in the API changes
such that it stores previous data as well as new data so I can map them and display them

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [entireData, setEntireDate] = useState([]);
  

  let arr = [];
  const fetchAPI = async () => {
    const API = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api");
    const json = await API.json();
    let results = json.results;
    setData(results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPI();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {}, [data]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <p>
          {data.map((val, idx, arr) => {
            return val.login.username;
          })}
        </p>
        <img
          src={data.map((val, idx, arr) => {
            return val.picture.large;
          })}
          alt="getPicFromJson"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this

```
  const fetchAPI = async () => {
    const API = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api");
    const json = await API.json();
    let results = json.results;
    // here you get the old data and pushing the results into Data
    Data.push(results)
    // and setData to Data that has (Data + results)
    setData(Data);
  };
```

also if you want to have your data after refreshing your browser , you may need to store `Data` in localstorage and get the initial data from that